# Some bugs in PendingIntent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

From my application I set the Activity to go Bluetooth Setting option. If I am clicking the Home Button from the BT setting activity and try to relaunch the application it wont work can anyone give me idea about it?

```
notification=new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "", System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent in=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, in, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), "app name", "Application is now running, press here to open", pi);
notifyMgr.notify(id, notification);
```

Comment: what does not work? please explain the expected flow and what is not working?

Comment: From my Blue-tooth setting Activity I want to call my MainActivity through the PendingIntent How can I?